# Let $a, b, c \in Z$ such that $\gcd(a,c) = d$ for some integer $d$. Prove if $a\mid bc$ then $a\mid bd$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is what I have tried.

If $\gcd (a,c) = d$ then you can pick $x, y$ such that $d = ax + cy$

So to show $bd = la$, multiply $b$ into above to get $bd = bax + bcy$

And since $bc = ma$, $bd = bax + may$

Is this sufficient proof? I think I need to get rid of the $b$ in $bax$

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You don't need to get rid of b in $bax$.

Comment: It's fine for me. Why should you get rid of the $b $ in $bax$? You can factor out $a$ in the r.h.s., that's the main point.

Comment: What is $l$ and $m$?  Where did those come from?  Oh.  $l = \frac {bd}a$ and $m = \frac {bc}m$.... Yes, other than the style point you need to introduce $m,l$ the proof is valid. And no, then $b$ is $bax$ is not a problem.

Comment: alternative proof, the way I tend to do things which is neither easier nor more illuminating than yours, just different:  Let $a=a'd;c=c'd$ Then $\gcd(a',c')=1$ then $a|bc\implies a'|bc'\implies a'|b$.  So $a'd=a|bd$.  (Mine uses a modified Euclid's Lemma; yours Bezout's-- kind of interesting as your proof is nearly *exactly* how we would prove Euclid's lemma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sufficient proof. You have shown $bd = a(bx+my)=al$, which is what you wanted.